# Conversion of an unordered list to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to build a JSON object from a UL element in Javascript.

I have this list structure:

```
<ul id="trainingmenu">
    <li class="tmnode"><span id="M5lx9n" class="tmname">menu 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="tmnode"><span id="M66p48" class="tmname">menu 2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="tmnode"><span class="tmname" id="Mschr">menu 3</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="tmnode"><span id="Mu03e0" class="tmname">menu 4</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the JS:

```
var treeObject = {};

    function treeHTML(element, object) {
        if (element.tagName=="UL") { element=element.firstChild; }
        object["id"] = element.firstChild.id;
        object["name"] = element.firstChild.innerHTML;
        var nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName('LI');
        if (nodeList[0]) {
            object["nodes"] = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
                object["nodes"].push({});
                treeHTML(nodeList[i], object["nodes"][object["nodes"].length - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    treeHTML(document.getElementById("trainingmenu"), treeObject);
    alert(JSON.stringify(treeObject));
```

..and this is the output I'm getting:

```
{"id":"M5lx9n","name":"menu 1","nodes":[{"id":"M66p48","name":"menu 2","nodes":[{"id":"Mschr","name":"menu 3"}]},{"id":"Mschr","name":"menu 3"},{"id":"Mu03e0","name":"menu 4"}]}
```

It's part-working and this is the format I want - picking out the id and name fields from the childNode of each LI element. But it's repeating nodes - menu 3 appears twice

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Che95/)

I've probably screwed up the recursion but having stared at it for 2 days haven't worked out how. Can anyone help?

Comment: FWIW, I'm slightly surprised the code works at all.  If the HTML code is really as written then `element.firstChild` on the outer `ul` _should_ return the whitespace text node between the `ul` and the `li`.  In newer browsers you would use `.firstElementChild` to ignore the text nodes.

Comment: True - this is just for readability; I removed the breaks in the fiddle. However, I didn't know about .firstElementChild (!) so I've learnt something there. Thanks for that.

Comment: @WindsorAndy don't forget that `firstElementChild` is a moderately recent addition to the DOM spec - it may not exist on older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alnitak mentions you should use `.children` or `.childNodes` property instead of the `.getElementsByTagName()` method. The following snippet uses Array prototype's `.filter()` method for filtering the `ul` children and `.forEach()` for iteration.

```
function treeHTML(element) {
    var o = {};
    o.id = element.firstElementChild.id; 
    o.name = element.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
    o.nodes = []; 
    [].slice.call(element.children).filter(function(e) {
        return e.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'ul';
    }).forEach(function(ul) {
        [].slice.call(ul.children).forEach(function(li) {
           o.nodes.push(treeHTML(li));
        });
    });
    return o;    
}
var treeObj = treeHTML(document.getElementById("trainingmenu")
                               .firstElementChild);
```

Here is an alternative solution which should also work in older version of IE:

```
function children(node, selector) {
    var res = [], nodes = node.childNodes, l = nodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeType === 1) {
            if (selector && nodes[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === selector) {
               res.push(nodes[i]);   
            } else if (!selector) {
               res.push(nodes[i]);
            }  
        }
    }
    return res;
}

function treeHTML(element) {
    var o = {};
    var span = children(element, 'span');
    o.id = span[0].id; 
    o.name = span[0].innerHTML;
    o.nodes = []; 
    var ul = children(element, 'ul'), n = ul.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var li = children(ul[i]), l = li.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
           o.nodes.push(treeHTML(li[j]));
        }
    }

    return o;    
}

var root = document.getElementById("trainingmenu");
var treeObj = treeHTML(children(root)[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XZ54G/

Comment: A very elegant solution, BlackSheep. This question is turning into a JS masterclass for me.

Comment: You can shim the ES5 array functions, but you can't shim `firstElementChild` and `children`.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, you are right, shimming ES5 array functions when IE8 and below do not support those properties is pointless. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @BlackSheep FWIW, I would suggest re-writing the whole thing to just use DOM0 properties.  It'll be slightly longer but then completely portable.

Answer (score 1):

It's repeating nodes because `element.getElementsByTagName` is finding *all* descendants, not just children.  You might want to test that `nodeList[i].parentNode == element`.

Alternatively just iterate through all of the element's child nodes (`element.childNodes` or `element.children`) directly, and look for those with `tagName == 'li'`.  In well formed HTML you should only find (whitespace) text nodes and `li` elements in the child list of a `ul` element.

Comment: ... and comment nodes.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, those too!

Comment: I decided to stick with getElementsByTagName("LI") but only pass those that are direct descendents into an array for further processing. Because there's a UL element in the way when iterating through, I decided this was too fiddly. Your insight set me straight though, thank you very much